# Procedure or function expects parameter ' which is not supplied

Tags: c#, gridview, sql-server-2008-r2

hello friends i face one issue for load the data to grid view.

the page load event call the one method like loaddata() inside i write the code this

```
  using (SqlConnection Sqlcon = new SqlConnection(strCon))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                Sqlcon.Open();
                cmd.Connection = Sqlcon;

                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.CommandText = "SP_Marketing";
                //cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Sno", (object) ?? null.Value));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@pvchAction", SqlDbType.VarChar,50));
                cmd.Parameters["@pvchAction"].Value = "select";
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@pIntErrDescOut", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

                SqlAda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                ds = new DataSet();
                SqlAda.Fill(ds);
                GridViewSample.DataSource = ds;
                GridViewSample.DataBind();
            }
        }
```

the find the store procedure records in sqlada caught error like"Procedure or function expects parameter @dateemailed  which is not supplied"

```
ALTER PROCEDURE SP_Marketing          
(            
 @Sno   int  =0,            
 @DateEmailed datetime,            
 @DateResponded datetime,            
 @EmailRep  varchar(100)=null,    
 @Type   varchar(100)=null,    
 @Country  varchar(100)=null,    
 @State  varchar(100)=null,    
 @NameoftheCompany varchar(100)=null,    
 @website  varchar(100)=null,    
 @FirstName  varchar(100)=null,    
 @LastName  varchar(100)=null,    
 @Title   varchar(100)=null,    
 @Email   varchar(100)=null,    
 @Telephone  varchar(100)=null,    
 @Capabilities varchar(100)=null,    
 @Focus   varchar(100)=null,    
 @pvchCreatedBy  varchar(100)=null,            
 @pvchAction   varchar(50)=null,            
 @pIntErrDescOut  int output    
)            
AS            
 BEGIN            

   if(@pvchAction='select')         
    begin    
     SELECT sno,Dateemailed,dateresponded,emailrep,[type],country,[state],     , nameofthecompany,website,Firstname,Lastname,Title,email,telephone,
capabilities,  Focus FROM Emailmarketing  WHERE active=1  
  end


else if(@pvchAction='insert')    
  begin    
  INSERT INTO EmailMarketing(DateEmailed,DateResponded,EmailRep,[Type],    
  Country,[State],NameoftheCompany,website,FirstName,LastName,Title,Email,Telephone,Capabilities,Focus,Createdby,CreatedDt,Active)VALUES(@DateEmailed,@DateResponded,@EmailRep,@Type,    
  @Country,@State,@NameoftheCompany,@website,@FirstName,@LastName,@Title,@Email,@Telephone,@Capabilities,@Focus,@pvchCreatedBy,GETDATE(),1);    

  end    
  else if(@pvchAction='update')    
  begin    
  UPDATE EmailMarketing SET DateEmailed=@DateEmailed,DateResponded=@DateResponded,EmailRep=@EmailRep,[Type]=@Type,Country=@Country,[State]=@State,NameoftheCompany=@NameoftheCompany,website=@website,FirstName=@FirstName,LastName=@LastName,Title=@Title,Email=@Email,Telephone=@Telephone,Capabilities=@Capabilities,Focus=@Focus,Updatedby=@pvchCreatedBy,UpdatedDt=GETDATE()    
  WHERE Sno=@Sno;    
  end    
  else if(@pvchAction='delete')    
  begin    
  UPDATE   EmailMarketing SET Active=@pvchAction WHERE Sno=@Sno;    
  end    

    IF (@@ERROR <> 0)             
   BEGIN             
  SET @pIntErrDescOut = 1            
   END            
  ELSE            
   BEGIN            
  SET @pIntErrDescOut = 0            
   END     



END
```

Comment: I don't see any code for you add `@DateEmailed` as a parameter in your `cmd`? Error message isn't clear?

Comment: Quite a clear error message that you need to supply that parameter to your stored procedure.

Comment: Please avoid the [`sp_` prefix](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx): "Avoid the use of the **sp_** prefix when naming procedures. This prefix is used by SQL Server to designate system procedures. Using the prefix can cause application code to break if there is a system procedure with the same name."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following parameters don't have default values in your stored proc:

```
@DateEmailed datetime,            
@DateResponded datetime,
```

So you always need to provide those values in the code:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DateEmailed", SqlDbType.DateTime));
cmd.Parameters["@DateEmailed"].Value = DateTime.Now; // Provide your value here
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DateResponded", SqlDbType.DateTime));
cmd.Parameters["@DateResponded"].Value = DateTime.Now; // Provide your value here
```

Comment: What for? What is written on SO, stays on SO :) If you like the answer, mark it as accepted or upvote, that's the way this site works.

Answer (score 1):

If you are calling a stored procedure, in addition to the `NULL` issue someone mentioned above, there is a type mismatch issue. For instance I was getting the "Expects parameter that is not supplied" error, when I was supplying the parameter.

After pulling my hair out for a while I found that the procedure had an input parameter of `nvarchar(50)` and I was passing a string that was longer than that. Apparently any kind of mismatch is reported the same as not providing (which in a way I suppose it is).

So you may want to double check data types and sizes on both ends.